# I want to Understand SetState and Prevstate in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, I am using wizard form in my project which enable user to next and prev step. I copied some code for next button but honestly did't understand what it mean.

Can you please help me understand the following code:

```
next() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ current: prevState.current + 1 }));
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)? It has  all you need to know. Even if you don't get something after reading this, then you may ask at specific part.

Comment: What do you expect now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for contributing.

As has been suggested in the comments, you probably should take a look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), but since you are a new contributor, I thought I'd try to answer your question.

#### How State and setState Work

Every component react class has a "state." When "state" is updated, the component will re-render. `setState` is the method used to update the state of the component. `this` refers to the component itself.

Your component `state` object might look like this initially: `{ current: 0, something: 'foo' }`.

#### What next() is doing

When you call `next()`, then `setState` will also be called. `setState` is called with a callback. The callback provides an argument, here named `prevState` - prevState is the current `state` on the component, so `{ current: 0, something: 'foo' }`.

The return value of `setState` will set any fields on the state object that are provided. After calling `this.setState`, the new value of `component.state` will be `{ current: 1, something: 'foo' }`.

#### re-render

A re-render of the component will be triggered because a shallow comparison of the new state and previous state objects will return `false`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar you need to be more clear in what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the walk-through.  As a beginner, it's often hard to properly interpret the documentation. I was a little stumped by the docs for a while bc I thought prevState was something I needed to supply, not something that is supplied for me.

Comment: Can you please explain the arrow function that is nested in there?  ie why can't `prevState =>` be deleted?

Comment: Is it that the argument for setState has to be a function and that setState will supply this function with the current state as its parameter?

Comment: If you want to dynamically set the state (i.e. increase the value by 1), then you need some reference to the previous value. When setState is provided a callback, the first argument is the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you'll need to look into the docs itself to know more about [how setState works](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Further here, I want to specify why shall we need it?

In react states are not mutable ie. to say you cannot change the state directly like:

```
state = { current: 1 }
// ...and somewhere in your code
this.state.current = 2 // won't work
this.state.current = this.state.current + 1 // also, no luck
console.log(this.state.current) // 1
// the reason is immutable
```

So, you'll need to update the state without mutating it. And thus, react provides us publicly to use setState.

setState has two arguments: updater and callback.

The updater can accept state and props. So that you update the state checking its condition based on state and props or somehow else you'll want.

The callback is provided here in the setState so you may know its effect like what the `current` is now. See an example below:

```
this.setState((state, props) => { // previous state, previous props
  // you may additionally check some condition
  // or combine state and props
  // like, state.current + props.value
  return { current: state.current + 1 }
}, () => {
// ^^- callback
  console.log(this.state.current)
})
```

BTW, there are some different options to use the setState:

```
a) without updater and callback
eg. setState({current: 2})
b) with updater param only
eg. setState(()=>({current: 2}))
c) with updater and callback
eg. see preceding example of code
d) without updater but with callback
eg.  setState({current: 2},()=>console.log(this.state.current))
```

Comment: So if the argument for setState is a function then setState will supply this function with the current state as its parameter?