# State updates may be asynchronous, what is exactly this.props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
state = { 
  persons:[
    {id:"cbhc", name:"surya",age:26,sex:"male"},
    {id:"rgt", name:"sachin",age:36,sex:"male"},
    {id:"cbcchc", name:"rahul",age:46,sex:"male"}
  ],
  showdetails:false,
  **counter:0**,

};
```

The above was the state of data in my application:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

What was exactly here: `props.increment` ????

My piece of code:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

I want to know what is `props.increment` ??

my skeleton of component:

```
import React from "react";
//import mystyles from "./person.module.css";
//import Studentoutput from "./cockpit/cockpit";
const Singlestudent = props => {
  console.log("child component skeleton rendering...");
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={props.click}>{props.name}</p>
      <p>{props.age}</p>
      <p>{props.id}</p>
      **<p>{props.increment}</p>**
      <input type="text" onChange={props.update} value={props.name} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Singlestudent;
```

since my state data is embedded inside with nested array and object, using map method to structure my skeleton comp data as below:

```
// import React from "react";
// //import mystyles from "./person.module.css";
// const Studentoutput = props => <input type="text" value={props.name} />;

// export default Studentoutput;
import React from "react";

import Singlestudent from "./student/singlestudent";
const Studentinfo = props => {
  console.log("child component details rendering...");
  return props.details.map((studentinfo, index) => {
    return (
      <Singlestudent
        key={studentinfo.id}
        name={studentinfo.name}
        age={studentinfo.age}
        **increment={props.increment}**
        update={props.updated(studentinfo.id)}
        click={props.clicked(studentinfo.id)}

      />
    );
  });
};

export default Studentinfo;
```

i passed increment={1} , hardcoded it.

now finally passing the above to my main parent which renders on browser

```
return (
      <div className={mystyles.parent}>
        <Studentinfo
          details={this.state.details}
          updated={this.updateStudentHandler}
          clicked={this.deleteStudentHandler}
          **increment={1}**
        />
     </div>
    );
```

from the above code snippet i'm changing my counter value through **updateStudentHandler**

```
 updateStudentHandler = id => event => {
    //debugger;
    const studentIndex = this.state.details.findIndex(d => d.id === id);
    console.log(studentIndex);
    let duplicate = {
      ...this.state.details[studentIndex]
    };
    duplicate.name = event.target.value;
    const dd = [...this.state.details];
    dd[studentIndex] = duplicate;
    this.setState({
      details: dd
    });
    this.setState((referencetoprevState, Props) => {
      return {
        counter: referencetoprevState.counter + Props.increment
      };
    });
  };
```

as soon as i change the text in input box, my counter should update but it returns NaN, why ????
refer to below screenshot attached

[output of counter variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh1LW.png)

but if i change the below code

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
      return { counter: state.counter + props.increment };
});
```

with a **value (9000)** instead of **props.increment** results in updating the counter value as expected.

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
      return { counter: state.counter + 9000 };
});
```

why i need to provide explicitly value not just like **props.increment** similar to **state.counter** because state.counter is taking its value as 0 from the previous state but props.increment not taking the value 1 from increment={1} from jsx of user defined component which is **Studentinfo** comp ??
Any limitations/reasons ??

Comment: Props is what is passed to your component: `<YourComponent increment={1} />`, did you not mean to use this.state.increment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to Understand SetState and Prevstate in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562135/i-want-to-understand-setstate-and-prevstate-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

As the React documentation states:

> When React sees an element representing a user-defined component, it passes JSX attributes to this component as a single object. We call this object “props”.

I suggest to read further the official docs, especially [Rendering a Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component) part.

Additionally `setState()` one [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) explains further:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});
```

> Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with state.

**In summary:**

Basically you are using `setState()` function's updater argument in your code which takes two parameters, `state` and `props`:

1. `state`: is a reference to the component's state - mentioned above - at the time the change is being applied aka previous state.
2. `props`: current properties of the component.

You can think of like having the previous state and current properties of the component in two different arguments.

I hope this helps!

Comment: refer to my edited code and provide your valuable input

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got , just like setting values to an object inside state, we provide values to props in the element tag which is jsx, so from my above code i figured out few things.

As per my understanding i believe that updater function for setState has two params, which basically sits in order as the first param would be previous state and the second is the current property of component.
Here my main component which renders on page with all other child components is .
 
so, props.increment is coming from **Appl** which extends Component from "react".

removing increment prop from my skeleton and body of skeleton i.e, from **Singlestudent** and **Studentinfo** comps

so finally :

```
 this.setState((referencetoprevState, Props) => {
      return {
        counter: referencetoprevState.counter + Props.increment
      };
    });
```

would be:

```
 this.setState((referencetoprevState, Props) => {
      return {
        counter: referencetoprevState.counter + 1
      };
    });
```