# how to set value in hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, use-state

I have a problem with hooks in ReactJS
as you see here i defined a prop that should call from child component
but when i want to change the value by calling change component it doesn't work and my state doesn't set.
can someone help me?
**don't forget to read the comments**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Collection from "./Collection";
import ReminderPeriod from "./ReminderPeriod";

function SingleReminderPage() {

    const [collection, setCollection] = useState(null);
    
    const setSelectedCollection = (e) => {
        setCollection(e);
        console.log(e); // returns the true value
        console.log(collection); // returns null
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Collection onChoosed={(e) => setSelectedCollection(e)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleReminderPage;
```

Comment: could you post the code of `Collection` component where you are calling the function ?

Comment: `setCollection` will not update state synchronously. By the time this `console.log(collection);` gets executed, state might not get updated that's the reason why it's still printing `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use setState with a callback function

```
const setSelectedCollection = (e) => {
    setCollection((state)=> {...state, e});
}
```

setCollection(e) - wont update the state immediately.

[I want to Understand SetState and Prevstate in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562135/i-want-to-understand-setstate-and-prevstate-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you around, the useEffect will be called on each colletion update

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Collection from "./Collection";
import ReminderPeriod from "./ReminderPeriod";

function SingleReminderPage() {

    const [collection, setCollection] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(collection)
    }, [collection])

    return (
        <div>
            <Collection onChoosed={(e) => setCollection(e)} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleReminderPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the setCollection is called after the logging action to check something like that you can print the collection value on the component itself

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Collection from "./Collection";
import ReminderPeriod from "./ReminderPeriod";

function SingleReminderPage() {

    const [collection, setCollection] = useState(null);
    
    const setSelectedCollection = (e) => {
        setCollection(e);
        console.log(e); // returns the true value
        console.log(collection); // returns null
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {collection}
            <Collection onChoosed={(e) => setSelectedCollection(e)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleReminderPage;
```